# How to skip top key of json?

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

There is JSON with root key `playlist` that fetch from Retrofit Interface. `Gson` library can't parse it to data class. Is there way to do "step into" playlist key before create model?

```json
{
    playlist: {
        name: "",
        description: ""
    }
}
```

```
data class Playlist(val name: String, val description: String)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that website [json to Kotlin](https://jsonformatter.org/json-to-kotlin), it's very useful specially with long json data.
For your case you have two objects, the main object and playlist object, so you need two data classes:

```
data class PlaylistResponse (
    val playlist: Playlist
)

data class Playlist (
    val name: String,
    val description: String
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data class PlaylistObject(
    val playlist: Playlist
)

data class Playlist(
     val description: String,
      val name: String
)
```